# Statistics problem asking for maximum range, but with seemingly no bound.

Tags: statistics

I came across this problem:

> A set of seven integers has a median of 73, a mode of 79, and a mean
>   of 75. What is the least possible difference between the maximum and
>   minimum values of the set?

So, I begin by using the information to construct some members of the set:
$$\_\text{ }\_\text{ }\_\text{ }\underline{73}\text{ }\underline{79}\text{ }\underline{79}\text{ }\_$$

And an equation:$$\frac{a+b+c+73+79+79+d}{7}=75$$

I didn't see where to actually begin, so I decided to try out some examples. While I did, I saw that $\frac{50+71+72+73+79+79+101}{7}$ works, but $101-50$ is absurdly incorrect as the answer was $8$.

Any help on how my example was wrong, and how to approach and solve this problem? Thanks!

Max0815

Comment: bro holy carp why am i so regarded bruhhhh i couldve just double read the problem wtfffff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is simply irrelevant since the question asks for the least, not largest possible difference between the max and min values.

The minimum value must be at most 71, since if it was 72 or 73 the mode would not be 79; it would be either 72, or 73, or tied between 72 and/or 73 and/or 79.

Since the maximum value is at least 79, the least possible difference between the max and min values is at least 79 - 71 = 8.

The sequence 71, 72, 72, 73, 79, 79, 79 satisfies all constraints and has difference 8. Thus the least difference is at most 8.

In conclusion, the least possible difference is 8.

Comment: Ah, I read the question wrong!